# Editing TIN surface by polygon using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing, tin, flood

I'm doing a 2D hydraulic flood study of rivers in a 63 km2 basin. I have a raster of the topography (1x1 meters) that I have passed to TIN using ArcMap. Giving a z=0.3 meters, I get a TIN network with too many triangles in areas where I do not require so much density. I am only interested in a high density close to rivers.

Is it possible to edit, collapse, decrease the density of the TIN mesh using a feature such as a polygon?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is Yes, but creating and editing a TIN surface is beyond the scope of this site, you need to be training yourself if you are asking such questions. As you have tagged this as an ArcMap question, I suggest you head over to Esri training and complete the [Creating 3D Data using ArcGIS](https://www.esri.com/training/catalog/57630433851d31e02a43eeb3/creating-3d-data-using-arcgis/) course.